# Class of unknown type with an upper bound

Tags: java, generics

Suppose i have an interface and two extending classes, like below;

```
public interface UpdateHelper<T>{
   List<T> getItemsToOperate();
}

public class ProfileUpdateHelper implements UpdateHelper<Profile>{
//class logic
}

public class PlayerUpdateHelper implements UpdateHelper<Player>{
//class logic
}
```

Player and Profile are two concrete classes. When i design my classes like above everything is fine. But i would like to introduce another abstraction layer between concrete Profile and Player classes such as;

```
public abstract class Updatable{
//common attributes will be here
}
public class Player extends Updatable{
}
public class Profile extends Updatable{
}
```

And use my helper classes like that;

```
public interface UpdateHelper<T>{
   List<T> getItemsToOperate();
}

public class ItemUpdateHelper<? extends Updatable> implements UpdateHelper<Updatable>{
//class logic
}
```

I think I should use wildcards since any class instance extending updatable can be used with helper classes and it should not matter which sub-class instance is being used.
But when i write like above i get an unexpected wildcard error just after class names and code won't get compiled. Am i missing something, doing something wrong or something like that can't be done in java. By the way I am using java 8.

Comment: `ItemUpdateHelper<Updatable>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use wildcards in class declaration. Instead, you pass a type parameter like `T`:

```
public class ItemUpdateHelper<T extends Updatable> implements UpdateHelper<Updatable>{
...
}
```

You can specify concrete implementation of `Updatable`:

```
ItemUpdateHelper<Player> playerHelper = new ItemUpdateHelper<>();
ItemUpdateHelper<Profile> profileHelper = new ItemUpdateHelper<>();
```

or not:

```
ItemUpdateHelper helper = new ItemUpdateHelper();
```

Comment: that is what i am trying to avoid since if i use them like that than i have to specify the concrete class type when i create a new instance of the ItemUpdateHelper class.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to. I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You would want to implement it like,

```
public class ItemUpdateHelper<T extends Updatable> implements UpdateHelper<T>{
}
```